# POI how delete blank row?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have a method that deletes unnecessary rows. How can I now remove the empty row between the rows?

And  how can I remove rows from two different sheets in one method?
because l  getting a bug now

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1208) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1253) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.RowIterator.processReport(RowIterator.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
```

method

```
      private void deleteRow(Row row) {
                Cell cellCustomer = row.getCell(customerColumIndex);
                if (cellCustomer.getColumnIndex() == customerColumIndex) {
                    if (!cellCustomer.getStringCellValue().equals(reportConst.value())){
                        newSheet.removeRow(newSheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()));
                    }else(condition){
                   (HOW DO THIS)  **row.getSheet().removeRow(row.getSheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()))**;
                }
            }
```

RowInterator

```
List<RowProcessor> rowProcessorList;

@Override
public void processReport(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    for (RowProcessor rowProcessor : rowProcessorList) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        rowProcessor.initialize(sheet);
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            if (row.getRowNum() > 0) {
                rowProcessor.processRow(row);
            }
        }
    }
```

I try this solution

```
 private void removeEmptyRows(Sheet sheet) {
        Boolean isRowEmpty = Boolean.FALSE;
        for(int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            if(sheet.getRow(i)==null){
                isRowEmpty=true;
                sheet.shiftRows(i + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, -1);
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            for(int j =0; j<sheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();j++){
                if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j) == null ||
                        sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString().trim().equals("")){
                    isRowEmpty=true;
                }else {
                    isRowEmpty=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isRowEmpty==true){
                sheet.shiftRows(i + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, -1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I think through RowIterator it generates errors for me. I use it in a few more classes and would like to be consistent

Comment: Can you provide details about the RowIterator class? - it is not part of POI afaics.

Comment: @PJFanning Hi I add this class